# how to make sure getter is not null

Tags: java

*It is a dump question sorry about that i have been while not using java.*

I have a setter/getter class `ListMainItem` I want to set and get a String from it but i am getting null value.

```
    ListMainItem object = new ListMainItem();
    String[] images = {"A","B","C"};

    final ArrayList<ListMainItem> list = new ArrayList<ListMainItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
        object.setImages(images[i]);
        list.add(object);
        String test = object.getImages();
        System.out.print(test);
```

the value test is always being null what i am doing wrong here

Listmain class

```
public class ListMainItem  implements Parcelable{


    String id;
    //String name;
    public String url;
    String images;

    ListMainItem (Parcel in){
        this.id = in.readString();
        //   this.name = in.readString();
        this.url = in.readString();
        this.images= in.readString();
    }

    public ListMainItem() {
    //    this.id = id;
    //    this.url = url;
          this.images = images;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setImages(String Image)
    {
        this.images=images;
    }
    public String getImages()
    {
        return images;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.id);
        // dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.url);
        dest.writeString(this.images);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ListMainItem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ListMainItem>() {
        public ListMainItem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ListMainItem(in);
        }

        public ListMainItem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ListMainItem[size];
        }
    };



}
```

Comment: Where does the loop end? Show code for getter/setter

Comment: show ListMainItem  class

Comment: You need to include the ListMainItem code. Chances are, you never actually get/set the value (wrong reference probably)

Comment: Check what `setImages(String str)` and `getImages` methods do. Bug is most probably hidden in `setImages(String str)` method - it does not set a value returned by `getImages` method.

Comment: There's no way to know why getImages() returns null without actually seeing what it's doing.

Comment: Probably a case of `image = image` instead of `this.image = image`.

Comment: @Tezra list main added

Comment: public void setImages(String Image)
    {
        this.images=Image;
    }

Comment: Every (good) IDE should have told you your fault...

Comment: @Clijsters trust me , my ide didnt show me the fault or i wouldnt be able to compile my code.

Comment: That wouldn't prevent you from compiling the code, since it isn't an error, but a proper configured IDE shows a warning.

Comment: That's why i precised a **good** one ;) I trust you. Your code is sytactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the catch

```
public void setImages(String Image)
    {
        this.images=images;
    }
```

You need to change `setImages(String Image)` to `setImages(String images)`

Also, I'm wondering if you code really compiles properly as below line of code doesn't seems to be valid. You are initializing String array by character array ?

```
String images[] = {'A','B','C'};
```

**Suggestion for correction :**

Below line of code is an example of **Assignment to Itself**. You should comment the assignment.

```
public ListMainItem() {
//    this.id = id;
//    this.url = url;
      this.images = images;
}
```

After each iteration, you are suppose to add new object to list, which you aren't doing here instead you are updating same object and adding its reference. That also means all the element has same object reference and will return same value. So, you should be creating a new object in each iteration.

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    object = new ListMainItem();
    object.setImages(images[i]);
    list.add(object);
```

Comment: my problem i guess in the constructor i am did't add string image, so i added but how to call it  here ?  ListMainItem object = new ListMainItem();

Comment: No, constructor is to initialize the state, if you aren't doing anything there java will initialize with default value anyway. Also, you are setting this value later anyway

Comment: then why i am still getting null value ?

Comment: its fixed now , the issue was  in setImages(String Images) when i change to image it is fixed.  i have beeng coding for 10 hours so silly things get in you in trouble thank anyway

Comment: great. I would also like to suggest few more input.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void setImages(String Image) {
    this.images = images;
}
```

`images` in this context is equal to `this.images` - you are setting this to itself and the `String Image` input parameter is being ignored.

If you want this to work, do `this.images = Image". It would be also a good idea to stick to conventions and abandon the capital letter:

```
public void setImages(String images) {
    this.images = images;
}
```

Comment: I fixed to ( String images) but still getting null , should i add in the constructor string .. for example like that ListMainItem(String name);

Comment: @Moudiz I tried running it and fixing the setter fixed everything. Make sure that you are running the updated version

Comment: anyway in the setter i fixed the constrocter like this public ListMainItem(String images) { this.images = images; } then what should i assing here ? ListMainItem object = new ListMainItem();

Comment: @Moudiz I am afraid I do not have enough information to answer this question - you need to provide more context

Answer (score 1):

Your setter is wrong

```
public void setImages(String Image)
    {
        this.images=images;
    }
```

The param is Image, so image references the global variable (wrong case broke reference).

Comment: I fixed to ( String images) but still getting null , should i add in the constructor string .. for example like that ListMainItem(String name); ?

Comment: @Moudiz in your test class, you have `String images[] = {'A','B','C'};`, which doesn't compile (`'A'` is a char, not String, and Java won't allow that) Is that really your test code?

Comment: yes yes it is. The string in my case have different values so i write this code throught my hand

Comment: anyway in the setter i fixed the constrocter like this     public ListMainItem(String images) {

          this.images = images;
    }
then what should i assing here ?          ListMainItem object = new ListMainItem();

Comment: @Moudiz I think the error is in your test code now, so you should change that so that the test code here, and what you are running are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have initialised 'String images' in wrong way. Try using " " instead of ' ' while writing string values in it.
You are getting null value because of the default values it takes during initialisation